# How do I go live with the classic account setup

Tags: paypal

I am using the classic API. Everything works fine in the test environment and now I want to go live but all the information I see on the PayPal developer about going live doesn't discuss how to do this with the classic API.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which API or API's you are specifically trying to use but as long as you have a live account that is already enabled for the services you are going to be using, you just need to replace your credentials.  You will need to replace the sandbox credentials with your live ones, and change the environment/endpoint to the the live site.  If you dont already have an account set up on live, you will need to sign up for the account.  Depending on what service you are trying to use, you may have to wait for an approval before you can use it.