# Where can I find or create a profile to go live with Classic API with signature

Tags: api, paypal, digital-signature, credentials

I have completed testing in the sandbox using the credentials which are available from Developer > Dashboard > Sandbox > Accounts > [Expand email address] > Profile

Where do I find or create credentials to go live? Is this still in the developer portal, or are these in the live profile and settings? I've looked everywhere I can think of. The password and signature I need are not under Profile and Settings > Account Information > Manage User or API Access.

The following question states that you just need to replace your sandbox credentials with your live ones, but where can these be found or created?

[How do I go live with the classic account setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385063/how-do-i-go-live-with-the-classic-account-setup)

Comment: Is this for paypal? I can't even tell what product you are trying to connect to.

Comment: Sorry, yes PayPal. I came in to StackOverflow via a link from PayPal and at that point it looked like the context of my post was a PayPal [sub forum] and  so no further reference seemed necessary. I have now added a PayPal tag.

Comment: The [tag:signature] tag is reserved for *method* signatures.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found where to create these credentials:

Tools > API Access > Set up APIs > Request API credentials > Request API signature > Agree and submit

Seems obvious now I guess.